# Why does no line appear when using Interpolate Line in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, elevation, topography

I'm attempting to make an elevation profile from a DEM in ArcMap using the Interpolate Line tool.  I've done this before, and it has worked great--basically I just draw a line with Interpolate Line, then click Profile Graph to get the elevation profile.  However, for some reason, it's not working now: when I draw out my line, nothing shows up on the map.  I don't get a line, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I've searched online for an answer, but to no avail.

Any tips?

Comment: What were the precise and detailed steps that you performed when you tried to do this beginning with starting ArcMap?

Comment: Also, what does the Geoprocessing... Results report on the status of the job? You can also try disabling background geoprocessing, so the job progress appears in a window. Please [Edit] the question.